# 8051 programmer not working when laptop lid removed despite suggestions in comments

Tags: microcontroller, programming, 8051, interference, parallel-port

**UPDATE**

I took a suggestion of disconnecting my external monitor from my laptop and the results were the same. What I did notice however is that the AT89S52 chip always reports the correct signature when I use the new circuit (with the filters) but when I use the older version (without filters), the chip couldn't be recognized half the time.

Now I'm curious. would my problem be solved if I wrapped plastic wrap around the circuit and aluminum foil as the outer layer and only cut the portion off where I insert and remove parts?

**Question**

I'm baffled as to what is really going on. I'm trying to make a circuit that can successfully program an AT89S52 everytime.

I made two versions of my circuit. In the first version, I didn't include the components in red boxes (resistors in red boxes before were wires) decouple each IC and it only had 1 100uF capacitor and 1 47nF capacitor (not included in schematic) for decoupling.

This is where things get crazy.

When my laptop lid was still intact with my laptop and I was using my first circuit, everything worked continuously. Sadly the hinges to the lid broke and now I have to use my laptop with an external monitor. I included a picture of my current setup. I then used the exact same circuit with the same software setup and everything else EXACTLY the same, and now I get continuous failures in programming (example: byte verification fails).

So now I took a hunch that maybe with the absense of the lid, the laptop is sending unwanted spikes to my circuit making my circuit think there's extra clocks.

I did some research and then I redid my circuit by adding components shown in red boxes. I did a double-filter setup on the clock line using RC filters (330 ohms for R and 10nF for C). I even made my software write one byte every 100 microseconds while I was on lunch and I still get errors.

The resistors feeding to the VCC pins of each IC are 0 ohms but I wanted to try ferrite beads so I tried them and they didnt work.

I also tried a parallel port extension cable and that gave worse results (couldnt validate signature).

In all other tests (minus those with the extension cable attached), the chip signature can always be read correctly.

Is there something I can do hardware wise to rectify this issue (before I install a new laptop lid) even if it means another capacitor?

The chip number of the other IC I used in my circuit is a 74HC125

[image: circuit]

**Sample of layout used in test**
[image: Sample]

Comment: Bizarre. I'm not quite sure why would you have to low-pass the SCK signal.

Comment: Maybe there's a crack on the laptop's motherboard?  What made the hinges break?

Comment: I did it because I figured if the laptop was sending a bunch of transistons at high speed to the circuit (EMI?) then by using a low pass filter on the clock line, I can make the microcontroller ignore wrong data. I'm not sure how theres a crack on the motherboard. The rest of the laptop works. and the hinges broke over time. I bought the laptop 2 years ago and the lid was never replaced.

Comment: "The resistors feeding to VCC are 0 ohms" say what now?

Comment: I meant the VCC pins on each IC have resistance of 0 ohms

Comment: I did a minor update to my question to clarify the 0 ohm resistance and to identify the other chip. Makes me wonder. should I change that 74HC125 chip to a 74HCT or even a 74LS? hmm

Comment: That is  a really bad photo.. and whats with the extra twisted pair antenna that does not look like it goes anywhere?

Comment: a laptop old enough to have a parallel port does not need an excuse for the hinges to break.

Comment: that "twisted-pair" of red and black is the 5V power feeding into the circuit. I twisted it to lower chances of interference. Also, the other so-called-antenna with the three wires is used to power my other programmer (at89c2051) which also worked when the laptop lid was in place. I just wanted to make an easy system for me to plug and unplug components.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the LPF after the buffer, there may be some weirdness involving 'the edges being too slow'. There may be some minimum slew rate specified for the SCK somewhere in the datasheet, be sure to stay within that.

Comment: BTW: I'm not really surprised, having an unshielded circuit right next to a video outlet is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Have you tried removing the monitor while the programming is happening?

Comment: maybe the monitor is the problem but ironically the monitor is substantially newer so youd think that would have no effect. im not at my computer at this second but ill look into that idea

Comment: im baffled again. based on comments im starting to think i should invest in some metal box that i can open and close everytime i program the chip to block out "low speed rf interference"? and do such boxes even exist for me? i mean i dont wanna screw and unscrew screws to a box if i wanna program like. 45 chips an hour. could i get away with surrounding other cables from my laptop with ferrite?

Comment: OK, I modified my programmer code itself so that it issues resets between each major phase (from erase to write to verify). It sort-of helps but I'm not getting any known pattern back when validating written data (at least this time it doesn't return a bunch of FF's)

Comment: Does plugging the laptop in versus having it on battery power make any difference?

Comment: I managed to get the programming working at least once by increasing delays to 100+uS per step and by doing almost one second delays between switching between reset and normal states. I'm going to see if I can improve my code more.